# Laravel says call to undefined function bzcompress

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I want to use bzcompress to Compress a string into bzip2 encoded data.
how should I install bzip2 in cPanel? From PHP PEAR Packages I can not find bzip2 module using php 5 what would be the problem?

Error:

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\bzcompress()
```

Controller code:

```
    $order['cart'] = utf8_encode(bzcompress(serialize($cart), 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the php installation guide: http://php.net/manual/en/bzip2.installation.php

Basically it tells you that the support for it needs to be passed at compile time